# What does 'restricted_action' error code in 'conversation.create' mean?

Tags: slack-api

I have got `channels:manage` scope for the bot using the OAuth flow, and I am using the `conversations.create` API to create channels. The API is successful in some Slack workspaces and is not in others. The API is returning a `restricted_action` error code.

While I understand that it could be because of some workspace admin settings, I am unable to figure out what setting it is. I am unable to give a workaround for my customers.

Can someone throw light on what setting it could be, so that I can better serve my customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely similar to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55872067/slack-bot-fails-to-send-message-to-restricted-general-channel-via-chat-postmessa), which is that the user authorising your app does not have the permission to perform the action themselves and thus cannot grant it to the bot.

A workaround for this might be to detect that the action is being restricted, and DM the installing user asking for them to have an administrator (or someone with the right privileges) install the bot. Slack allows admins to restrict channels creation to admins only, which is likely what is happening here.