# How to perform certain actions after a Slack workspace's admin approves the installation of the app?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Edit: I'm using Django and inside the `DjangoInstallationStore.save` method I create a channel, join the bot to it, and post a message into the channel.

It seems that if a user attempts to install the app to a workspace where there might be admin restrictions, the installation and bot are created but the channel cannot be created (`restricted_action`) or joined (`channel_not_found` ) and the members of the channel cannot be viewed (`channel_not_found`).

I'm investigating if I have a bug in my code but also wonder if there is anything I missed about Slack API as to if certain restrictions in the workspace could cause such scenarios to happen? Cheers.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you mean when you say "desirable actions". Until your app is properly installed your app won't be able to listen for any events.

Comment: Hi Sandra, yes. I'm using Django and inside the `DjangoInstallationStore.save` method I create a channel, join the bot to it, and post a message into the channel. It seems that if a user attempts to install the app to a workspace where an admin needs to approve it, the installation and bot are created but the channel cannot be created (restricted_action) or joined and the members of the channel cannot be viewed.

Comment: The answer was already [provided here previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67603707/what-does-restricted-action-error-code-in-conversation-create-mean).